# Why does Chrome not redirect using meta refresh

Tags: html, google-chrome, redirect, meta

An application that I work with has a PL/SQL package that creates a page and uses a function to create META tags.

It creates a webpage with a META tag exactly like this :

```
 <META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" NAME="Refresh" CONTENT="1; URL=PaymentSubmit.html">
```

The problem is that Chrome does not like the NAME="Refresh" attribute.  It does not redirect the page, although it does redirect properly in IE and Firefox

If I remove the NAME attribute, so that it looks like this it works in all browsers :

```
 <META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="1; URL=PaymentSubmit.html">
```

What's going on here?  I can't find a W3C standard for META redirect, so does every browser make up it's own rules ?  I'm not sure if it ever worked in Chrome, but since I never heard any bug reports I assume it used to work in Chrome.

Anyone have a similar problem ?

Thanks

Comment: Here is some W3C verbiage on REDIRECT vs Refresh: http://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/reback

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you check [the w3c wiki](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/meta) you can find the following quote:

> Exactly one of the name, http-equiv, and charset attributes must be specified.

It mean's it is not valid html that both - `name` and `http-equiv` attributes are set.

Read [this W3C's HTML and XHTML Techniques test on meta refresh](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H76#H76-tests):

> Find all meta elements in the document. For each meta element, check
>   if it contains the attribute http-equiv with value "refresh"
>   (case-insensitive) and the content attribute with a number greater
>   than 0 followed by ;'URL=anyURL' (where anyURL stands for the URI that
>   should replace the current page).

The behavouir of the other browsers is not wrong, but chrome is more strict.

**More details** about the correct behavouir - and the valid reference - are available at http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#attr-meta-http-equiv-refresh

Answer (score 10):

### As far as browser support:

The support for `<meta>` refresh is there even in IE6

### The syntax to be used is:

Place inside `<head>` to refresh page after 5 seconds:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5">
```

Redirect to http://example.com/ after 5 seconds:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; url=http://example.com/">
```

Redirect to http://example.com/ immediately:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://example.com/">
```

If you plan to support javascript disablers (*Which I don't think you should do* :)

Do this:`<noscript><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=url here"></noscript>`

It is not a part of HTTP standard.

However, there are alternatives:

For refreshing the page after 5 seconds, do the below:

```
<body onload="javascript:setTimeout(function(){ location.reload(); },5000);">
```

If you want to redirect after 5 seconds, then do the below:

```
<body onload="javascript:setTimeout(function(){ window.location = 'http://example.com';},5000);">
```

If you want to redirect immediately:

```
<body onload="javascript:window.location='http://example.com'">
```

But there isn't any alternative for javascript disablers (*yippee!!*)

### Conclusion:

So, my suggestion, would be to use my javascript alternatives, because they are *not* going to be replaced.

But `<meta>` refresh tag may be discontinued in the coming years.

More reading : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh

Answer (score 2):

For the `<META` tags, Microsoft has published specific guidelines:

> [Page and site guidelines for SEO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff724048(v=expression.40).aspx)

Specifically, for the `<meta http-equiv="refresh">` element, Microsoft states the following:

> *A page redirect should provide both a message with the new page location and sufficient  time for users to read the message. A page redirect with a time-out period of **less than five  seconds** may result in a lower search-engine ranking.*
>
> *To redirect a page, **consider using an HTTP redirect instead**. An HTTP redirect is more  likely to transfer the authority of the old page to the new page.*

Personally, instead of a `<meta` refresh tag, I would recommend you use a [301 Redirect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection). In PHP you could do, for example, the following:

```
<?php
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
header("Location: http://www.yourdomain.com/newpage");
?>
```

This method is better than the `<meta` refresh because usually a 301 redirect includes the address to which the resource has been moved. Web browsers will typically follow 301 redirects to the new location automatically, without the need for user action.

According to [some](http://www.web1marketing.com/glossary.php?term=301+Redirect) definitions of `301 Redirect`, it would even preserve old positions:

> *A 301 redirect should be used whenever a website is moved to a new domain name (URL) so that search engines will quickly change their indeces and, in theory, preserve the search engine rankings that the site had at the previous domain.*

All this is in line with the fact that many shady websites use `<meta` refresh to open unwanted websites (spam/ advertisements etc.). Hence I would conclude that the refresh meta tag should **not** be used.

For the other meta tags, please read the following: [18 meta tags every webpage should have](https://www.iacquire.com/blog/18-meta-tags-every-webpage-should-have-in-2013).

Keep in mind that not all meta tags are of crucial importance; for example, Google says it [does not use the keywords meta tag in web ranking](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.nl/2009/09/google-does-not-use-keywords-meta-tag.html).

But remember: it is *Better to have, and not need, than to need, and not have.*

Just don't use the `<META refresh` ;)